# Multiple physics bodies in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a 40x40 rectangle node, and I want to detect when the bottom touches a platform.

I tried this

```
let feet = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: hero.frame.size.width, height: 1), center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(hero.frame.size.height/2 - 0.5)))
```

then set the `categoryBitMask`, `collisionBitMask`, `contactTestBitMask`and added it to the hero

```
hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [feet])
```

But in `didBeginContact` the `println()` doesn't print.

I need a body for the bottom of the rectangle and one for the top, because if hero hits a platform from below the collision should push him down.

**Update**

Here is how I set the bit masks

```
let heroFeetCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 0
let edgeCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 1
let groundCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 2

let feet = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: hero.frame.size.width, height: 10), center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(hero.frame.size.height/2 - 5)))
feet.collisionBitMask = edgeCategory | groundCategory
feet.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory

feet.categoryBitMask = heroFeetCategory


hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [feet])
hero.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
hero.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

hero.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
hero.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
hero.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
hero.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.0

hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
hero.physicsBody?.mass = 0.0641777738928795

world.addChild(hero)
```

and for the ground

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(38, 38))
ground.name = "groundName"
ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(self.frame.size.height/2 - ground.frame.size.height/2))

ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground.size)
ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = edgeCategory | heroFeetCategory
ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = heroFeetCategory
ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
world.addChild(ground)
```

And how I detect if they touch

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var notTheHero: SKPhysicsBody!;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        notTheHero = contact.bodyB;
    } else {
        notTheHero = contact.bodyA;
    }

    println(notTheHero.node) // print "heroName"
    if (notTheHero.categoryBitMask == groundCategory) {
        println("touch began?"); // is never called
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code you used to set your bit masks for the hero and the platform

Comment: I set bitmasks for the feet, since i want to know only when the hero is above the platform.

Comment: ok then the code for the bitmasks for the feet and platform.

Answer (score -1):

collision is fine, but when you print the node's name through the physics body with `notTheHero.node` you only access the `SKNode`, and not the `NSString` property of its name. Instead, try something like `println(notTheHero.node.name);`

Comment: When you print the node, inside is the name. Why I need println(notTheHero.node.name) then?

Comment: You're accessing the name property on the node thats why.

Comment: And this help with the collision how?